# Cognos 8+ - Use Query Results in an Html Object

Tags: cognos

I'm pretty new to cognos Reports Studio,
but was wondering if there's a way to take
the results of a query, and work with them
inside of an HTML object.

Say I have a query that returns 1 record with the following:
-Genre
-Artist
-Album
-Song

and I want to fill an html object with the following:

'<%=song%> is a good example of <%=genre%> by <%=artist%>, from their album <%=album%>'

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to use ASP.net shorthand echo as the basis for your idea, and unfortunately, I don't think you can use anything like that in Cognos. The idea would be to use a data container/block, such as a list report, and create a data item inside of it. There, you could concatenate the static elements together with the data items you're retrieving from the database, for example:

```
[Song] || ' is a good example of ' || [Genre] || ' by ' || [Artist] || ', from their album ' || [Album]
```

Hope that helps.